# Is it too late learn physics properly now that I am a 3rd year student?

Tags: soft-question, education

This may seem a bit silly. I am 21 years old 3rd physics undergraduate. Even, after taking a three year undergrad physics course it feels like I haven't really understood what I learnt, didn't learn anything systematically and I feel like I should start all over again. Is it too late to learn physics "properly". And, can someone guide me through the process.

Thank you

Comment: Do not despair.  In some ways, you have a big advantage in realizing that you don't really understand the material yet.  Here's something that has worked for me:  Tutor younger students, while doing your best to see problems through their eyes.  You will be forced to understand and explain the material from multiple perspectives, which will greatly increase your understanding.  As you tutor, *write your own book* - at least in the form of thorough notes you can refer to later.  Don't be in a hurry.  List your own questions, and answer them step by step.

Comment: Please try to come in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar).

Comment: 3yrs surely isn't enough to learn physics and there is no proper way to learn physics. During these first 3years of undergad you learn a great amount of physics stuff and sometimes it might feel that you haven't understand anything . But I think as you start a grad you really start to digest all those physical concepts. Learning something does not require a lot of time, but understanding things really takes time!

Comment: You can find much more stuff related to this on Academia.se